# Creating a vector in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am ashamed I need assistance on such a simple task.  I want to create 20 normal distributed numbers, add them, and then do this again x times. Then plot a histogram of these sums.  This is an exercise in Gilman and Hills text "Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models".

I thought this would be simple, but I am into it about 10 hours now.  Web searches and looking in "The Art of R Programming" by Norman Matloff and "R for Everyone" by Jared Lander have not helped.  I suspect the answer is so simple that no one would suspect a problem.  The syntax in R is something that I am having difficulty with.

```
    > #  chapter 2 exercise 3
    > n.sim <- 10  #  number of simultions
    > 
    > sumNumbers <- rep(NA, n.sim) #  generate vector of NA's
    > for (i in 1:n.sim)  #  begin for loop
     +{
     +     numbers <- rnorm(20,0,1)  
     +     sumNumbers(i) <- sum(numbers) #  defined as a vector bur R 
     +                                   #  thinks it's a function
     + }
 Error in sumNumbers(i) <- sum(numbers) :     
 could not find function "sumNumbers<-"
 > 
 > hist(sumNumbers)    
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug    
 Error in hist.default(sumNumbers) : 'x' must be numeric     
 3 stop("'x' must be numeric")   
 2 hist.default(sumNumbers)  
 1 hist(sumNumbers) 
 >
```

Comment: You might want to tag with the language you are using in the future. It makes it a lot easier for your question to be seen by the right people.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. When you put parentheses after a variable name, the R interpreter assumes that it's a function.  In your case, you want to reference an index of a variable, so it should be `sumNumbers[i] <- sum(numbers)`, which uses square brackets instead.  **This will solve your problem.**
2. You can initiate `sumNumbers` as `sumNumbers = numeric(n.sim)`.  It's a bit easier to read in simple case like this.
3. By default, `rnorm(n)` is the same as `rnorm(n,0,1)`.  This can save you some time typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate an operation a specified number of times with the `replicate` function:

```
set.seed(144) # For consistent results
(simulations <- replicate(10, sum(rnorm(20))))
#  [1] -9.3535884  1.4321598 -1.7812790 -1.1851263 -1.9325988  2.9652475  2.9559994
#  [8]  0.7164233 -8.1364348 -7.3428464
```

After simulating the proper number of samples, you can plot with `hist(simulations)`.